# How to fix Error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value (type string) at path "_id" for model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

My current code for the /api/students/id route is as follows

```
router.get('/:id',asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{
    const student = await Student.findById(req.params.id)

        if(student){
            
             res.json(student)

        }
        else{
            res.status(404).json({message: 'Student not found'})
        }

}))

export default router
```

When I hit the /api/students/{correct-Id} it gives me the correct students details
however if i change the correct-Id to something different it gives me the following error ,

[image]

but I am expecting the correct error which is the one i have added 'Student not found'

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Did you try casting it manually, like ```mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)```?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your controller?

```html
try {
///
} 
catch (error) {
   res.status(404).json({mesage: error.message})      
}
```

If so, change error.message to  'Student not found'

Comment: hey yes i have that part and also the message:Student not found part

Answer (score 0):

The id that you are sending is not an objectId and you are directly passing it to findById function of your model and mongo does not recognise that as an objectId hence it is failing.

for your error "student not found" you need to pass a valid objectId.

If you need that error in case of invalid id too then you have to check first
something like [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#simplified-isvalidobjectid-and-separate-isobjectidorhexstring)

But ideally in case of invalid objectId the error should be something like Invalid Id , because you are knowing it before that the data can not exists. "student not found" would be a wrong message.